# /etc/profile.d/kwin.sh file doesn't exist

Tags: kubuntu, kde, kwin

I've found a fix for my screen tearing with nVidia drivers, and many have said this works, but the file I need to edit in order to use the fix is not there. Any ideas?

I have Kubuntu 14.04.2 installed.

Comment: Explain why the down vote. This is a legit problem and downvoting is NOT gonna help make my question any better or help me fix it. If there is an issue, then tell me, downvoting should be left for bad/dangerous answers and troll questions.

Comment: Where did you find this fix? `kwin.sh` doesn't seem to be something from the repository packages: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=kwin.sh

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA#Avoid_screen_tearing_in_KDE_.28KWin.29
Someone said it worked with Kubuntu 14.04, he posted a link to this exact page..

Comment: Looks like it's a file you are supposed to create with either of the contents given, depending.

Comment: Ok, the guy said he edited the file, so I assumed it was supposed to already be there..

Comment: But yeah thanks for the help, I'm gonna see if this works, sorry for the trouble, I should've read more closely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the file yourself and add the commands to it. Just leaving this here in case anyone misunderstands what they are supposed to do. :)

Add these commands to an empty text file, and save it in /etc/profile.d as kwin.sh. If it doesn't work immediately, restart your computer or log out and back in.

```
export __GL_YIELD="USLEEP"
export KWIN_TRIPLE_BUFFER=1
```

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA/Troubleshooting#Avoid_screen_tearing_in_KDE_.28KWin.29